# What do the partitions /dev/disk1s* in filesystem mean (disk storage management)?

Tags: ios, storage

When U run `df -h`  I get the following output (formatted as table for better viz).
What do all these /dev/disk1s* mean? Can it be that I lose space due to some imposed partition?

| Filesystem | Size | Used | Avail | Capacity | Mounted on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /dev/disk1s5s1 | 233Gi | 14Gi | 22Gi | 40% | / |
| devfs | 193Ki | 193Ki | 0Bi | 100% | /dev |
| /dev/disk1s4 | 233Gi | 5.0Gi | 22Gi | 19% | /System/Volumes/VM |
| /dev/disk1s2 | 233Gi | 320Mi | 22Gi | 2% | /System/Volumes/Preboot |
| /dev/disk1s6 | 233Gi | 1.0Mi | 22Gi | 1% | /System/Volumes/Update |
| /dev/disk1s1 | 233Gi | 192Gi | 22Gi | 90% | /System/Volumes/Data |
| map auto_home | 0Bi | 0Bi | 0Bi | 100% | /System/Volumes/Data/home |

My OS version is BigSur (11.2.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `disk1s*` in `/dev/disk1s*` are identifiers for the APFS volumes and snapshot in the container with the identifier `disk1`. These are not partitions as stated in your question. The APFS container resides in either a single partition on a drive or two partition on separate drives. In your example, the APFS volumes and snapshot all share in the same APFS container. Below shows the sum of the volumes, snapshot and available space equal the APFS container size. There is no lost of space.

```
 disk1s5s1    14. Gi
 disk1s4       5. Gi
 disk1s2       0.320 Gi
 disk1s6       0.001 Gi
 disk1s1     192. Gi
 disk1s3        .569 Gi
 Available    22. Gi
           ------------
 Size        233. Gi
```

> Note: You did not include in your question the size of the unmounted Recovery volume (`disk1s3`). The value of 569 MiB came from my Big Sur installation. This value should be the same on your Big Sur installation.

Below was taken from `man diskutil`. I edited out the text that does not directly relate to the OP's question.

---

You are referring to disk identifiers. In your example, the (BSD) disk identifier string variously identifies a virtual logical volume.  It will take the form of `diskCsV`, or `diskCsVsS` where `C`, `S`, and `V` are positive decimal integers (possibly multi-digit), and where:

- `C` is an APFS Container.  This is a virtual disk constructed by
  APFS to represent a collection of APFS Volumes.  Multiple APFS
  Containers can be active simultaneously.
- `V` is an APFS Volume; it refers to a virtual logical volume that
  is shared out of an APFS Container.  For example, exported from
  an APFS Container designated as `disk1` there might be an APFS
  Volume `disk1s1`, mountable as a file system and usable for file
  storage via its mountpoint path.
- `S` is an APFS Snapshot; it refers to a frozen moment in time of
  the state of files on an APFS Volume.  For example, if APFS
  Container `disk6` has an APFS Volume `disk6s3`, and two APFS Snapshots
  have been "taken" on it, these, when mounted, might be
  designated as `disk6s3s1` and `disk6s3s2`. Zero or more snapshots
  can be persistently defined on a volume, but only "active"
  (mounted) snapshots have disk identifiers.

It is important for software to avoid relying on numerical ordering of
any of the parts.  Activities including but not limited to partition
deletions and insertions, partition resizing, virtual volume deletions
and additions, device ejects and attachments due to media insertion
cycles, plug cycles, authentication lock cycles or reboots, can all cause
(temporary) gaps and non-increments in the numerical ordering of any of
the parts. You must rely on more persistent means of identification, such
as the various UUIDs.

---